# What is source in spree payments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

There is a `source` concept in [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) payment method which I don't know; what is its usage and what does it refer to ? 
and There is nothing about it in the documentation.
Is there anyone who can explain it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the docs you find this part:

`Payments relate to a source which indicates how the payment was made`

It doesn't help that much

But in this [line 3](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/45cec5215763da26e0089415f4c49afffd683bd9/frontend/app/views/spree/payments/_payment.html.erb#L3) in they `_payment` partial has this piece of code `if source.is_a?(Spree::CreditCard)`

So I would assume source is related with "where the money come from"

Answer (score 0):

Acourding to [this](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/45cec5215763da26e0089415f4c49afffd683bd9/core/app/models/spree/payment_method.rb#L29), **source** responsible for processing the payment.

> The class that will process payments for this payment type, used
>   for @payment.source
>     e.g. CreditCard in the case of a the Gateway payment type
>     nil means the payment method doesn't require a source e.g. check

```
  def payment_source_class
    raise ::NotImplementedError, 'You must implement payment_source_class method for this gateway.'
  end
```